# Self-Closing tag swallowing his neighbour

Tags: jquery, html, css

If 2 tags are self-closed, should they be in the same position in hierarchy, or the next tag should be the child of the first one?

I always thought that both structures are syntactically the same:

Sample 1

```
<div>
<div class="bordered"></div>
<div class="bordered"></div>
</div>
```

Sample 2

```
<div>
<div class="bordered"/>
<div class="bordered"/>
</div>
```

However, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43sp1z7c/) is telling me, that the 2nd one is the same as:

Sample 3

```
<div>
<div class="bordered">
  <div class="bordered"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've detected that behaviour, when I've updated jquery in npm dependencies. While jquery versions up to 3.4.1 have converted Sample 2 to Sample 1, the newest one (3.5.0) is converting Sample 2 to Sample 3.

Which of this behaviours is correct?

Comment: the second is simply invalid. No need to think more, the browser will try to correct your error so better write a vaild HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DIV is not a void element (like `<br>` is), so [in modern HTML **it should not be self-closing**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html).

The browser engine **may** try to make things right, but usually `<div .../>` means `<div>`. So, the closing `</div>` will be inserted **intelligently**, which is common techspeak meaning "in the wrong place, but automatically".

Comment: OK thanks, it seems I've skipped some important information that I've considered not relevant. We're not using div's but custom tags (to replace with javascript).